# Pandas Convert object values used in Passive Components to float

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe of part numbers stored as object with a string containing 3 digits of values of following format:

1. Either `1R2`, where the `R` is the decimal separator
2. Or only numbers where the first 2 are significant and the 3rd is the number of 0 following:

- 101 = 100
- 010 = 1
- 223 = 22000
- 476 = 47000000

My dataframe (important are positions 5~7):

```
   MATNR
0  xx01B101KO3XYZC
1  xx03C010CA3GN5T
2  xx02L1R2CA3ANNR
```

Below code works fine for the `1R2` case and converts object to `float64`.
But I am stuck with getting the 2 significant numbers together with the number of 0s.

```
value_pos1 = 5
value_pos2 = 6
value_pos3 = 7

df['Value'] = pd.to_numeric(np.where(df['MATNR'].str.get(value_pos2)=='R', 
                    df['MATNR'].str.get(value_pos1) + '.' + df['MATNR'].str.get(value_pos3),
                    df['MATNR'].str.slice(start=value_pos1, stop=value_pos3) + df['MATNR'].str.get(value_pos3)))
```

Result

```
MATNR          object
Cap pF        float64
dtype: object
Index(['MATNR', 'Value'], dtype='object')
             MATNR  Value
0  xx01B101KO3XYZC     101.0
1  xx03C010CA3GN5T      10.0
2  xx02L1R2CA3ANNR       1.2
```

It should be

```
             MATNR  Value
0  xx01B101KO3XYZC     100.0
1  xx03C010CA3GN5T       1.0
2  xx02L1R2CA3ANNR       1.2
```

Following I tried with errors and on top there is a wrong value for 0 @ pos3 being 1 instead 0.

```
df['Value'] = pd.to_numeric(np.where(df['MATNR'].str.get(value_pos2)=='R', 
                    df['MATNR'].str.get(Value_pos1) + '.' + df['MATNR'].str.get(value_pos3),
                    df['MATNR'].str.slice(start=value_pos1, stop=value_pos3) + str(pow(10, pd.to_numeric(df['MATNR'].str.get(value_pos3))))))
```

Do you have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have understood your problem correctly, defining a method and applying it to all the values of the column seems most intuitive. The method takes a `str` input and returns a `float` number.

Here is a snippet of what the simple method will entaik.

```
def get_number(strrep):
    if not strrep or len(strrep) < 8:
        return 0.0
    useful_str = strrep[5:8]
    if useful_str[1] == 'R':
        return float(useful_str[0] + '.' + useful_str[2])
    else:
        zeros = '0' * int(useful_str[2])
        return float(useful_str[0:2] + zeros)
```

Then you could simply create a new column with the numeric conversion of the strings. The easiest way possible is using list comprehension:

```
df['Value'] = [get_number(x) for x in df['MATNR']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where the bug in your code is, but another option that I tend to use when creating a new column based on other columns is pandas' [apply function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
def create_value_col(row):
    if row['MATNR'][value_pos2] == 'R':
        val = row['MATNR'][value_pos1] + '.' + row['MATNR'][value_pos3]
    else:
        val = (int(row['MATNR'][value_pos1]) * 10 +
               int(row['MATNR'][value_pos2])) * 10 ** int(row['MATNR'][value_pos3])

    return val

df['Value'] = df.apply(lambda row: create_value_col(row), axis='columns')
```

This way, you can create a function that processes the data however you want and then apply it to every row and add the resulting series to your dataframe.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will also try this one. As I am relatively new in Python I can't judge the pros and cons between the 2 solutions. They look very similar to me